# Where's the data about reset PC / Windows repair actions in activity history?

Tags: windows-10, reset

Where can I find the data about [reset PC / Windows repair](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recovery-options-in-windows-31ce2444-7de3-818c-d626-e3b5a3024da5#bkmk_reset_pc) events in the [activity history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/-windows-activity-history-and-your-privacy-2b279964-44ec-8c2f-e0c2-6779b07d2cbd)?

Comment: Unclear : Reset will clear/reset all events and history. Please explain better your need.

Comment: @harrymc Oh, it sounds logical... but I assumed that there is some kind of partial reset, or if there is no such thing, then Windows records this event (reset) in activity, along with a report that it saves to the desktop (there is a folder with a file where it is described what was deleted during the reset)

Comment: Reset will return the computer to its original state as regarding Windows. The option to conserve user data, if specified, does not apply to Windows files or registry. If the option was not specified, the disk is basically formatted to be empty before returning Windows.

Comment: If you Reset your PC data like that is lost